# Why local variables in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have generated a functional component to make the parent component readable and better structured.

The following does not work, that is: the condition never holds although console.log prints showed the required values.

```
const UpdateIcons = ({products, move2Program, onSaveTable}) => {

//the condition never fires even if console.log shows A, B, C as expected

    if (products['intake_mgr_decision'] === 'A' 
         && products['intake_family_decision'] === 'B' 
         &&  products['intake_status'] === 'C')
            return <button type="button"  className="btn btn-success pull-left" 
                        onClick={move2Program}>JOIN</button>

    return <button type="button"  className="btn btn-success pull-left" 
                        onClick={onSaveTable}>UPDATE</button>
  }
```

Adding local variables solved the problem.

**My question is WHY? What's the explanation?**

The following works

```
const UpdateIcons = ({products, move2Program, onSaveTable}) => {

    let mgr_decision = products['intake_mgr_decision']
    let family_decision = products['intake_family_decision']
    let status = products['intake_status']

    if (mgr_decision === 'A' &&  family_decision === 'B' &&  status === 'C')
            return <button type="button"  className="btn btn-success pull-left" 
                        onClick={move2Program}>JOIN</button>

    return <button type="button"  className="btn btn-success pull-left" 
                        onClick={onSaveTable}>UPDATE</button>
  }
```

Comment: can you check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xbxqkk, and expose your full code demo that would be better

Comment: @Jayavel I think I managed to recreate the issue. Can you see my modifications? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xbxqkk?file=Hello.js

Comment: @Jayavel The main difference was using ```<Functional-C products={products} />``` and not ```{Functional-C(products)}``` - My question is WHAT AM I MISSING?

Comment: @Jayavel https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gm8ip7?file=index.js

Comment: can you check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crkbqf ? read the comments , hope you will got a point

Comment: @Jayavel THANKS! for your effort. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you have to find a small analyze between function that return elements which takes arguments and functional component that returns elements which takes props.

Consider the below example :

```
 //here is the difference, when you use function, function takes arguments as it is.

  const  UpdateIcons = (products) => { 

  // if you use this as component props will be like products props will return the products object again, here you have to use {products} destructuring or products.propducts["One"]

  //like this const  UpdateIcons = ({products}) => { 

    if((products["One"]  === "A") && (products["Two"] === "B") && (products["Three"] === "C") ) {
      return <p>Conditional</p>
    }
    return <p>Show Always</p>
}

   class MyIssue extends Component {
     render() {
       const { products } = this.props;
        return ( 
          <div>
           {UpdateIcons(products)}  
           {/*passing arguments here products will be {"One": "A", "Two": "B"}*/}

           <UpdateIcons products={products}   /> 
           {/* passing props , props will be same as products */}
      </div>)
      }
    }

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
            this.state = {
                products: {
                   "One": "A",
                   "Two": "B",
                  "Three": "C"
                }
            };
     }

     render() {
        return <MyIssue products={this.state.products} />
     }
   }
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crkbqf)